# Update AOSP Repo

Tags: android, android-source

Just getting started with AOSP builds. Following a (somewhat dated) tutorial, I began a repo sync for android-11.0.0_r17 (still running). Later, I discovered that android-11.0.0_r26 is actually the latest build for my target device.

Is it possible to update the r17 repo to r26 after it completes or should I abort the sync and start over with a new repo initialized to r26?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to update the r17 repo to r26 after it completes or should I abort the sync and start over with a new repo initialized to r26?

Both cases are workable, just reinit repo to `android-11.0.0_r26` after that and start sync again.

As for me, I would prefer to immediately abort and sync with the desired branch (with `-c` option), so as not to pull unnecessary things:

```
repo sync -c
```

Comment: Many thanks Nikolay. Very helpful, especially the -c option.